# Why is "doofer" pronounced ['doːvɐ] insead of ['doːfɐ]?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Hearing "Zwei Doofe, ein Gedanke" I could not recognize that [ˈdoːvɐ] refears to *doofe* (my mind tried to write *dowe* or *dowa*, but I didn't think of *f* first).

Is there any way to guess when *f* at the end of a word goes to [v] when pluralized (or extended in a vowel). Why is this *f* in *doofe* even voiced?

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/doofer) declares both prounciations as valid

Comment: Regional? I would always expect “f” in the SW.

Comment: I'm not in Gemany, but NRW/Niedersachsen used to be my whereabouts

Comment: Shouldn’t the question be why it is spelt with an _f_ instead of a _v_?

Comment: @Crissov, no, since both are generally pronounced the same in German.

Answer (score 2):

"Doofe" wird standardsprachlich [ˈdoːvə] gesprochen. Beachte das ə-Schwa am Ende, kein ɐ-Schwa.

Intervokalische -f- werden üblicherweise als stimmhaftes [v] (meist genaugenommen [ʋ]) realisiert.

In Süddeutschen Akzenten wird oftmals [f] gesprochen.

Das gleiche Phänomen tritt auf bei Wörtern wie Elfer oder Fünfer.

Comment: Die verlinkte Wiktionary-Seite gibt die Aussprache für "doofer", nicht "doofe" an, deshalb /ɐ/.

Comment: Hast Du irgendeinen Beleg dafür, daß intervokalische -f-
*üblicherweise* als /v/ gesprochen werden?
Die Anzahl der Wörter, bei denen ich -f- als /v/ spreche,
ist sehr begrenzt. Spontan fallen mir nur drei
Beispiele ein: "doofe", "Fünfer" und "Elfer" (= Elfmeter),
letzteres übrigens im Gegensatz zur "Elfe" /ɛlfə/ (= Fabelwesen).
Ich kann mich auch nicht erinnern, jemals jemanden gehört zu haben,
der "Affe", "Hefe", "Elefant", "Reifen" oder "dafür" mit /v/ spricht.

Comment: Nachtrag: weiteres Beispiel "Zwölfer".

Comment: Nicht-Beispiele trotz Ähnlichketen zu "Elfer", "Zwölfer": "Golfer", "Helfer"

Answer (score 0):

Soweit ich weiß ist *doof* die neiderdeutsche Entsprechung zu *taub* (taube Nuss ~ doofe Nuss). Hochdeutsches innervokalisches *B* entspricht dort regelmäßig *V* (s. schon Grimm's Grammatik des Deutschen, s. a. DWB/[Kobold](https://dwds.de/wb/dwb/Kobold)). Wegen der Auslautverhärtung im Norddeutschen ist das im Stamm ohne Endung nicht unterscheidbar.

---

Im Detail ist das alles sicher noch viel komplizierter. Zumal Niederdeutsch eine Sammelbezeichnung ist und es im urbanen Raum (hier Berlin) schon lange mit Hochdeutschen Mundarten wechselwirkt, sind die Zusammenhänge nicht mehr intuitiv nachvollziehbar.

Ob der Ansatz zu *taub* überhaupt richtig ist, dürfte insofern unbeachtlich sein. Für die Mehrheit der Sprecher ist es sicherlich eine lexikalische besonderheit, die in der Regel nicht weiter auffällt, außer beim Schreiben in späteren Stufen des Spracherwerbs (im Endstadium sozusagen).

Hierhin gehört bestimmt auch der *Struwelpeter*, wobei beachtlich ist, dass einige Sprecher das u in die Länge ziehen, wogegen andere quasi *strubbel-* sagen wollen, aber sicher *Gestrüpp* sagen, so dass der Reibelaut als Allophon des Plosivs mit komplementärer Distribution abhängig von der Vokal-Quantität erscheint, die im Mittelhochdeutschen noch teilweise kontrastierend war, bspw. singular [fɪʃ], plural [fɪ:ʃ]. Vgl. En. *dope*, *doofus*. <sub>Demnach könnte auch *Depp* hierher gehören. Vgl. weiters *(be)deppert* (unsicher), En. *to dip* (nicht zu verwechseln mit *dab, tap*), wie *bedröppelt*, *triefen, Tropf*, En. *drip, drop* (viz. *zerdeppern*).</sub>

Nach Kroonen's Aufarbeitung von Kluges Lautgesetz gehört *tief* (En. *deep*, vor-Proto-Germanisch \ *dʰewbʰnós [en.wiktionary]) zur gleichen Wortwurzel. Da die Betonung auf der Endsilbe gelegen war (und ein n auf den Konsonanten folgte), verhält es sich also scheinbar genau anders herum, der Konsonant wurde stimmloss und unterlag daher der zweiten großen Lautverschiebung, die in norddeutschen Mundarten nicht vollständig vollzogen wurde (daher *uff, up* statt *auf*, landläufig auch *Appel* für *Apfel*).

Vgl. *Stille Wasser sind Tief*.